# What is the purpose of ValidationContext when implementing IValidatableObject

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ivalidatableobject

I have implemented `IValidatableObject` several times and have never found out what the purpose of parsing `ValidationContext` to the Validate method is - my typical `IValidatableObject` implementation looks something like this:

```
 public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
 {
    if (Prop1 == Prop2)
    {
        yield return new ValidationResult(
              "Prop1 and Prop2 must be different.",
              new[] {"Prop1", "Prop2"});
    }
 }
```

Is there anything that I have missed that I could have used `validationContext` for?

EDIT: I'm using ASP.NET MVC and this is implemented in the class - not in the controller.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ValidationContext` contains `IServiceProvider` property. It is extension point to pass DI container to your validation attributes and Validate methods. 
You can use it, as example,  to validate against database without setting dependency on dbcontext in your model.

Comment: It helps to give an example about how to pass a DI container in this particular situation.

Comment: in asp.net mvc this can be done with creating your own validation provider.

Comment: Can you please give an example of this?? I'm really stuck trying to make validations properly and to see a potencial answer without code is really sad :(

Comment: This [blog post](https://andrewlock.net/injecting-services-into-validationattributes-in-asp-net-core/) shows how to use `ValidationContext` to get a service via DI. Basically: `var service = (IExternalService) validationContext.GetService(typeof(IExternalService));`

Answer (score 6):

You should retrieve `Prop1` and `Prop2` from validationContext. From your question it's difficult to say whether you are using WebForms (so you have code-binding with properties) or MVC (and if you are implementing this in the controller).

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
 {
    if (validationContext["Prop1"] == validationContext["Prop2"])
    {
        yield return new ValidationResult(
              "Prop1 and Prop2 must be different.",
              new[] {"Prop1", "Prop2"});
    }
 }
```